# Rich Faces Calendar/ css html

Tags: html, css, richfaces

This should be an easy question!
But I'm not so familiar with styling/css and html.

So therefore
Is there anyway to shorten the text boxes that come with rich:faces calendar?

and also the size of the pop up calendar that comes up?

The link to rich faces calendar is

http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/calendar.jsf?c=calendar&tab=usage

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size of the text box can be managed by `inputSize` tag available in `<rich:calendar`

And for the size of pop up calendar you will have to give the id of the component and accordingly override the classes of the richfaces css.

You can check the classes and values by `Right Click -> Inspect Element` in firefox (installing firebug).

For example when you inspect the popup you will find a table which will contain the id given by you and then apply the following style

```
.idAsSeen {
width : 80px;
height : 80px;
}
```

Comment: hmmm I've never played with firebug. I will do!! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Kevin - did you gave `id` to component? what id did u see in `table`? and `inputSize` should definitely help..

Comment: when you mean ID did you mean something like <rich:calendar id= "calendar"> and then .calendar{width: 80px; height: 80px;}

Comment: @Kevin- yes by ID i mean `<rich:calendar id= "calendar">` but not `.calendar{widt....`, you will have to `Inspect Element` the popup and the id u see in html for popup table is to be given there

Comment: I will play around with it and see if I can understand it. Thanks you so much for your time nik